# Чтение из postresql в java и запись результата в ArrayList

Tags: postgresql, база-данных, java, массивы, библиотеки

Как вообщем понятно из моих предыдущих вопросов Java я полностью не знаю, поэтому прошу отнестись с пониманием. Есть код на С++, читающий из `postgresql` базы данных

```
#include <iostream>

//using namespace std;

#include <stdio.h>
#include "libpq-fe.h"
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     main() {
    PGconn          *conn;
    PGresult        *res;
    int             rec_count;
    int             row;
    int             col;
    FILE            *stream;

    conn = PQconnectdb("hostaddr=192.168.143.93 port=5432 connect_timeout=10 dbname=NexentaSearch user=postgres password=postgres");
    if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connection to database failed: %s\n",PQerrorMessage(conn));
     puts("No connection");
        exit(0);
    }

    res = PQexec(conn, "select path from tasks order by id");

    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK) {
        printf("We didn't get the data");
        exit(0);
    }

    rec_count = PQntuples(res);
```

Хочу выполнить тот же самый запрос к `postgresql` базе данных на Java и записать результаты в `ArrayList<String>`. Помогите пожалуйста это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для начала необходимо соединиться с БД:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
ArrayList<String> arrayString = new ArrayList<String>();
String query = "тут запрос";

ResultSet res = con.createStatement.executeQuery(query);

while (res.next) {
    arrayString.add(res.getString("1"))
}
```

Comment: @G1yyK извините за непонятливость, но очень надо, поэтому уточню: где указывается имя хоста, порта (для `postgresql`), базы данных и в каком формате, а также какую библиотеку надо подключать?

Comment: String url = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.143.93:5432/NexentaSearch
Тебе еще нужно будет скачать драйвер http://jdbc.postgresql.org/index.html и через -classpath подключить его к своему коду.

Answer (score 0):

В С/С++ коннект делается через ODBC, в Java через JDBC - в частном случае через мост JDBC-ODBC. [Примеры здесь](http://www.javable.com/columns/jdbc/)